# "order by" option in the REST API?

Tags: feature-request, api

Is there a way to order the questions returned by this (or similar) query by date (or other criteria)?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20answers%3a0 do what you want?

Comment: yes, @JonClements, thanks! Should I delete this question?